# Ruby on Rails ajax 500 syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, internal-server-error

I have a static controller and users controller.

I have a users profile page and I want to use ajax to replace the existing code with a form partial. On the page, I have a edit button that routes to the edit action in the users controller and goes to the edit.js.erb view. In that view I have the following code:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render 'static/profile_form'%>").appendTo("#ajax-profile");
```

Everytime I try and make it work, I get an error like this:

```
Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 17:42:19 -0400

Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 17:42:19 -0400

Processing by UsersController#edit as JS

Processing by UsersController#edit as JS

  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

  Rendered users/edit.js.erb (1.0ms)

  Rendered users/edit.js.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms

SyntaxError (/Users/UserNameRedacted/Desktop/magazine_alive/yourcoolapp/app/views/users/edit.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
...tput_buffer.append=( j (render: 'static/profile_form' );@out...
...                               ^):
  app/views/users/edit.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'



SyntaxError (/Users/UserNameRedacted/Desktop/magazine_alive/yourcoolapp/app/views/users/edit.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
...tput_buffer.append=( j (render: 'static/profile_form' );@out...
...                               ^):
  app/views/users/edit.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
```

I have been creating all my users through the console, so I have yet to fill out a form for any user. Could that be a problem? There is no information to edit? I don't want a new/create view because I have a login page for users.

In my Users controller I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @user= User.find_by(session[:user_id])

    @user.create(user_params)

  end

  def edit

    @user= current_user

  end

  def update

    @user=current_user

    @user.update(user_params)

  end

private

   def user_params

    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,:last_name,:email,:bio,:avatar)

   end

end
```

Static Controller

```
def profile

    @my_articles = Article.all.order('created_at desc').where(:user_id => current_user).limit(5);

    @user= current_user

end
```

Comment: Show us `app/views/users/edit.js.erb`.  According to the error that is where the problem is

Comment: $('#ajax-profile').prepend(" <%= j (render: 'static/profile_form' %> ");

Answer (score 0):

So your error says:

```
app/views/users/edit.js.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
```

Its expecting a closing parentheses.  If you look at your code:

```
$('#ajax-profile').prepend(" <%= j (render: 'static/profile_form' %> ");
```

You will notice you have mismatched parenthesis.

I suspect that you need to change that code to this

```
$('#ajax-profile').prepend(" <%= j (render: 'static/profile_form' )%> ");
```